Supplying two collections of type, one of which is subset of another
I'm introducing Dagger into our application. I want to have access to two collections of a type, one of which is a subset of the other
How do I do it?
(Other than wrapping collections in distinct types -- that would be AllPeople and AllExceptJane in my example below)
Here's a failing MRE
package myown;

import dagger.Component;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Set;

@Component(modules = PersonModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface PersonComponent {
    @Named("jane")
    Set<Person> getAllPeople();
    @Named("exceptJane")
    Set<Person> getAllPeopleExceptJane();
}

package myown;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;
import dagger.multibindings.IntoSet;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Module
public class PersonModule {
    @Singleton
    @Named("jane")
    @Provides
    public Person jane() {
        return new Person("Jane");
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    public Person joshua() {
        return new Person("Joshua");
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("exceptJane")
    public Set<Person> allExceptJane(/*does Dagger have trouble with this part?*/ Set<Person> allExceptJane) {
        return allExceptJane;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("all")
    public Set<Person> all(@Named("exceptJane") Set<Person> allExceptJane,
                           @Named("jane") Person jane) {
        Set<Person> all = new HashSet<>(allExceptJane);
        all.add(jane);
        return all;
    }
}

package myown;

public class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

When you try to build it, you get
java: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @javax.inject.Named("jane") java.util.Set<myown.Person> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
      @javax.inject.Named("jane") java.util.Set<myown.Person> is provided at
          myown.PersonComponent.getAllPeople()

Dagger 2.16
